# Fetching events of room in Outlook calendar

Tags: javascript, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get events of rooms created in Outlook. I can fetch rooms with Graph API, then I'm using endpoint like this to get events of one specific room:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/zasadacka15@1t18wm.onmicrosoft.com/calendar/calendarView?$select=subject,start&StartDateTime=2023-01-01T00:00&EndDateTime=2023-01-01T00:00
```

I have all permissions I need, have events in calendar for this room created too, but every time (for every room) I get response like this:

> {"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('zasadacka15%401t18wm.onmicrosoft.com')/calendar/calendarView(subject,start)",
> "value": []}

I read a lots of answers here and everywhere else, but I'm not able to solve this problem.
(I'm using client_credentials flow.... Maybe I need to do impersonation, or does it have nothing to do with?)

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the specified date range. Does the time of the event match the specified date range? you specified 2023-01-01T00:00. By default the time zone is UTC. What's the start and end date time of your event in UTC.

Comment: For example one of my events starts at 8:00am and ends at 8:30am ... when I tried to specify time in UTC it doesnt work neither... but anyway, I need to get all events of this room, not only one specific event

Comment: have you tried to query the events endpoint as a test eg https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/zasadacka15@1t18wm.onmicrosoft.com/calendar/events if you do get events this way then you know your permission are good and it's just something to do with the time range your using

Comment: I still have same empty value response, even when I use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/pluvaren@1t18wm.onmicrosoft.com/calendar/events ... I tried to do this for every room, and value is still empty .... I'm logged as an application with client_credentials, so as is mentioned in documentation, I have these permissions: Calendars.ReadBasic, Calendars.Read.

Comment: sounds like something a little weird is going on give yourself delegate permission on one of those mailboxes and see if you get the same result in graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, if the mailboxes are regionalized in another language could be your picking up the wrong folder but I've never seen that issue happen with the Graph or EWS. You could try listing to folders and looking at the result for the Calendar endpoint as well in the Graph Explorer might explain a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem is solved. Problem was, that I did't created event for those rooms... I was thinking, that when I create event and as location select that room, it will append that event to that room. But nope, you need to create event AS room, to see room events. Thanks guyz for helping me, problem was banality, and this is little helper for those who will be dealing with something similar.